# How to play a media through the tag with exoplayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

As soon as I add a song to the concatenatingMediaSource I add a tag next to it, so I would like to know how to play a song through this specific tag.

```
 ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource2 = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
       .setTag(ctd)
       .createMediaSource(ssUriTeste);

       concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource2);
```

Obs: ctd is a reference number to the position of the song;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a function that returns the whole playlist.

Examining the functions in the API it looks like the best option for an application that jumps around a lot in the playlist is to have a copy of it outside the player and only load the current item.

However, if you need to access a specific item from the playlist using an unique ID, this will probably work.

- Register your playlist like the code you provided, you can use .setTag() or .setMediaId() to uniquely identify your tracks
- Get the playlist items with .getMediaItemAt()

```
    int count = player.getMediaItemCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MediaItem media = player.getMediaItemAt(i)
        if(media.mediaId == myDesiredId) {
            // do whatever you want with media
            
            // you can also use the index i as a starting point
            // to delete all previous items or to move the i-th item to 
            // the first position of the playlist with moveMediaItem
            
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note: You should evaluate if the loop with multipla calls to getMediaItemAt() cause a problem.